# Send email with a table inside

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, html-email, mailmessage

Im am creating an email using `MailMessage` and would like to embed a dynamically populated table.  I've set a `MailMessage` property to `IsBodyHtml` so I've already been able to insert HTML encoded text into the body of the email.  Using that I could easily create the top and bottom of the table, but creating the rows seems like a `StringBuilder` nightmare.

The table will have 6 columns and a variable number of rows that would be populated from a collection.  The requestor would prefer NOT to send the data as an attachment.

Any suggestions on how to best develop a better solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really not a `StringBuilder` nightmare at all.

You can build a class, call it `TableBuilder` or whatever you'd like, that will encapsulate this logic.

```
    public class TableBuider
    {

        private StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();


        public string[] BodyData { get; set; }
        public int BodyRows { get; set; }


        public TableBuider(int bodyRows, string[] bodyData)
        {
            BodyData = bodyData;
            BodyRows = bodyRows;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Since your table headers are static, and your table body
        /// is variable, we don't need to store the headers. Instead
        /// we need to know the number of rows and the information
        /// that goes in those rows.
        /// </summary>
        public TableBuider(string[] tableInfo, int bodyRows)
        {
            BodyData = tableInfo;
            BodyRows = bodyRows;
        }

        public string BuildTable()
        {
            BuildTableHead();
            BuildTableBody();
            return builder.ToString();
        }

        private void BuildTableHead()
        {
            builder.Append("<table>");
            builder.Append("<thead>");
            builder.Append("<tr>");
            AppendTableHeader("HeaderOne");
            AppendTableHeader("HeaderTwo");
            builder.Append("</tr>");
            builder.Append("</thead>");
        }

        private void BuildTableBody()
        {
            builder.Append("<tbody>");
            builder.Append("<tr>");
            // For every row we need added, append a <td>info</td>
            // to the table from the data we have
            for (int i = 0; i < BodyRows; i++)
            {
                AppendTableDefinition(BodyData[i]);
            }
            builder.Append("</tr>");
            builder.Append("</table");
        }

        private void AppendTableHeader(string input)
        {
            AppendTag("th", input);
        }

        private void AppendTableDefinition(string input)
        {
            AppendTag("td", input);
        }

        private void AppendTag(string tag, string input)
        {
            builder.Append("<" + tag + ">");
            builder.Append(input);
            builder.Append("</" + tag + ">");
        }

    }
}
```

The `AppendTableHeader`, `AppendTableDefinition`, and `AppendTag` methods encapsulate all of the tedious parts of the `StringBuilder`.

This is just a basic example as well, you can build upon it as well.

Comment: I just updated my TableBuilder class to something that more specifically suites your needs. This class has the headers hard-coded in because you mentioned they are always the same. However, since the rows are variable, this class will take in the number of rows and the data that will be populated within them. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This article is Lightswitch specific. But the example code shows how to use XHTML and embedded LINQ expressions to populate a variable row table in an HTML email. I think you should be able to adapt it to suit your application.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/01/27/how-to-send-html-email-from-a-lightswitch-application.aspx